# How to click one button that exists two times with same name?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I try to click a button named .red and the problem is that there are two buttons with same name so Cypress does not know which of them to click with command cy.get('.red').click()

Originally I thought I have to access my class before trying to click the button.

How can I use below code to click "red trash icon"?

```
<div class="one wide column">
    <div class="ui vertical right floated buttons">
        <a class="ui basic button" role="button" href="/admin/assignments/edit/37">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="cog icon"></i>
        </a>
        <button class="ui basic button">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="red trash icon"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cypress [.get()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Syntax) command accepts complex selector arguments. So if you wanted to trigger a click on an element that has `red`, `trash` and `icon` classes, you could do the following:

```
cy.get('.red.trash.icon').click()
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestion and it worked fine. Have a nice weekend @Sean

Answer (score 1):

The `red trash icon` is the `<i>` element of inside the button, not the button itself.

You should perform click on the button itself:

```
cy.get('.button').click()
```

And if there is more than one button with the selector you have set you can give it a specific class or a specific id:

```
<button id="whatever">...

cy.get('#whatever').click()
```

Notice the use of `#` for ids instead of the dot `.` as a class selector.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I learned from your help. Have a nice weekend @jeprbio

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using a too broad CSS selector.

You could either set a unique ID html attribute to your button and find it with `cy.get('#your-id')` or you could make a more specific CSS selector.

For example you could select the last button with .red class like this

`cy.get('button.red:last-of-type')`

or the first one line this

`cy.get('button.red:first-of-type')`

or the X element using something like button.red:nth-of-type() { ... }

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I learned from your help. Have a nice weekend @erwan

Comment: You're welcome, do not hesitate to mark my answer as the correct one if it resolved your problem.

Have a nice weekend too :) @hereinsweden

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the Cypress documentation, you should add a custom `data-cy` attribute instead of using generic selectors